# Connected components and diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{1}$ function. Show that connected components of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|f(x,y)=0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\neq 0\}$ are diffeomorphic to real line.

My thoughts: First, the connected components are the sets that satisfies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)> 0$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)< 0$

Now, I want to show these sets are diffeomorphic to real line.

With this condition, I can apply implicit function theorem. Then, exist $g:I\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is $C^{1}$ and $f(g(y),y)=0$.

But, now I don't know what I can do.

Comment: $f(x,y)=0$ in the set

Comment: @mfl That's fine. The empty set has no connected components, so all its connected components are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. (This is one of the reasons why I don't consider $\emptyset$ connected, just as I don't consider 1 prime.)

Comment: OK. I have misread the question

Comment: Your application of the implicit function theorem gives you the desired diffeomorphism locally, since you have mutually inverse differentiable maps $y\mapsto(g(y),y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$. Unfortunately, "locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$" doesn't imply "diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$." You still need to make sure these components are not circles, for example. Here you'll need to use that the sign of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ stays the same.

Comment: The sign stays the same because the function is $C^{1}$. Thanks, @AndreasBlass!